# Extjs: Ajax, Proxy, using JSON and JQuery for charting

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, extjs

I have never been as frustrated with a lack of examples/documentation as I have with extjs!  Can someone please shed some light on this:

I am beyond confused. I have a php passing this array:  (There will be more to my chart, but took out most for debugging purposes)

```
$rows = array ( 
                 "project" => "amt", 
                 "accepted" => 3400, 
                 "rejected"=> 2389, 
                 "deleted" => 1845, 
                 "undefined" => 2006
             );

$options = array("ONE"=> $rows); 
echo json_encode($options);
```

I thought I could just do this Ajax Request:

```
    /// GET AJAX DATA
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'extjs/turnin_chart/chart_data.php',
    success: function(response) {
       var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);  
       alert(text.ONE);

        }
 });
```

But after this I don't know how to integrate this data into my chart's store. I've seen examples just using $.ajax (jquery) and others with "proxy".   Sometimes they require a model.  Can someone please explain and give a good example on exactly HOW to use Ajax and JSON to pass remote data to an extjs chart?

EDIT:  The alert that is returned is "[object Object]".  When I dump the array I get the array printed.

Comment: Can you include the JSON request body returned by your `extjs/turnin_chart/chart_data.php`?

Comment: I added the alert that I receive. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: but ONE *is* an object :) use console.log instead of alert and you'll see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you call the lack of examples; there are dozens of examples at [Ext JS docs site](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example). Take a look at Chart examples to see how to create a Chart. [This Charting tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/drawing_and_charting) will also be very helpful.
On a related note, it seems that half of your problem lies in not understanding how Stores work. [See here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/data) for an introduction in Ext JS Data package.
I would suggest you to get your data retrieval straight first, and then move to Charts. Taking on the whole thing at once can be very confusing indeed.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on charting but a lack of examples on using remote data and ajax.

Comment: Well, there's quite a number of Grid examples and most of them use Stores this or that way. Take a look at [this one](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/restful/restful.html).